# Javascript FileReader worked on first try, but not anymore (no line of code has been changed)

Tags: javascript, html, file, file-upload, filereader

So I implemented a html input element to upload text files. Then I wanted to read the content of the text and save it to a string array. To do this (I'm using Angular 2) I imported the [filereader npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filereader)  to use the *readAsText* function. Now when I tried it for the first time it worked! It printed to text, that was read from the file into the console.

Then I removed the *console.log(line)* function and since then I get the following error: **"cannot read as File: {}"**. I tried to readd the *console.log(line)* function, but I keep getting the same error. I logged the file variable before it is used by the filereader and has the information about the file. I also tried different files and also the clear the input *(el.nativeElement.firstElementChild.value = null)*, but still the same error.

html:

```
<input hidden="true" type="file" id="fileUpload" (change)="SendSurveyDataToBackend()" [attr.multipleFiles]="multipleFiles ? true : null">
```

js:

```
SendSurveyDataToBackend(){
    let inputEl = this.el.nativeElement.firstElementChild; 
    document.getElementById('csvUpload').style.color = "white";
    if (inputEl.files.length == 0 || inputEl.files.length > 1) {
        document.getElementById('csvUpload').style.color = "red";
        return;  
    }

    let file = null;
    file = inputEl.files[0];
    let FileReader = require('filereader');
    const reader = new FileReader();

    let surveyDataSetsAsStrings:string[] = [];        
    let surveyDataSets:SurveyData[] = [];

    reader.onload = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.result;
        const allLines = file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        // Reading line by line
        allLines.map((line) => {
            surveyDataSetsAsStrings.push(line.toString)
            console.log(line);
        });
    };

    reader.onerror = (evt) => {
        alert(evt.target.error.name);
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);    

    for(var i = 0; i < surveyDataSetsAsStrings.length; i++){
        surveyDataSets[i].Id = parseInt(surveyDataSetsAsStrings[i].substring(0,2));
        surveyDataSets[i].Date = new Date(surveyDataSetsAsStrings[i].substring(42,61));
        surveyDataSets[i].PlayerCode = (surveyDataSetsAsStrings[i].substring(63,73));            
    }
    this.el.nativeElement.firstElementChild.files = null; 
    this.el.nativeElement.firstElementChild.value = null; 

    this.dataService.updateSurveyParticipants(surveyDataSets).subscribe( response => {
        if(response == 'success') // Http OK
            window.location.reload();
        else
        document.getElementById('csvUpload').style.color = "red";
    });   
}
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just had to remove the following line of code and it worked...

```
let FileReader = require('filereader');
```

My bad...looks like I did change a line of code after it was working...